# Mac app for automatically closing / opening certain apps according to profiles?

Tags: macos, applications

I am looking for a app that allows me to set profiles consisting of apps to close or open on profile change.

Example. The following processes are currently open

- Dropbox
- Chrome
- Foo
- Bar

After activating "cafe profile"

- Chrome
- Bar
- Terminal

Background: I work in cafes a lot. Most of the times, I forget to turn off dropbox, hangouts, and other background processes which drains battery. Upon realizing, I close everything from the process manager, but if I had a app which does that automatically, that would save me a lot of time.

I plan to write it myself but want to make sure it doesn't exist yet before doing doubled work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) might be the app you're looking for.

With this utility you can define different contexts based on various criteria (i.e. Wi-Fi name, attached peripherals), and execute tasks upon entering or leaving these contexts.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to pay some money for it there is the excellent Keyboard Maestro which can do a lot of things. There you can close and open Apps easily.

If you do not want to spend money I suggest you take some time to learn Apple Script. This is a free scripting language provided by Apple. Alternatively you can use shell scripts but I am not so sure if you can easily check which apps are running or not.